# How do I arrange the icons manually in the app menu?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen-shortcuts, menu, app-drawer, micromax-a110

I am using [Micromax Canvas 2 A110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromax_Canvas_2_A110) with [Android ICS 4.0.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.0.x_Ice_Cream_Sandwich). I installed few apps which are sorted randomly (or maybe alphabetically). I want to arrange the icons on the app menu manually. i.e. set frequently used apps on one page, games on second page and so on... I could not find any option to re-arrange them manually.

So, how do I arrange the icons manually in the app menu (app drawer)? I want to do this on ICS's default launcher (not third party launcher).

<sub>PS: [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9260/15857) is for **auto** arrange while I want manually.</sub>

Comment: I guess you're talking about the "app drawer" of your home screen? In this case, the "how to" would very much depend on the *Launcher* (homescreen app) used. E.g. with [GO Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) you could even create folders there, other launchers may have different features. So you could either try out different launchers -- or at least add the one you use to your question. (and no, "arrange" will not be a good tag)

Comment: @Izzy - Hello, I am talking about [Menu screen](http://tips4tech.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/IceCream-Sandwich-on-HTC-Sensation.png) not about [Home screen](http://japan.digitalsfolder.com/uploadfiles/japandigitalsfoldercom-1296460450/take-screenshots-on-android-3-0-honeycomb-tablets-with-screenshot-er_4.png). for Android's default (built-in) launcher.

Comment: *...set frequently used apps on one page, games on second page and so on...* Exact way I'm doing. See the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, As @ [Izzy said](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/how-do-i-arrange-the-icons-manually-in-the-app-menu#comment47823_36607), it *is* the **app drawer**. That's the place where all your installed app icons shown.

[image: App Drawer]

So, about your problem, there are two ways you can solve it. You can either go to a third party app like [Izzy said](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/how-do-i-arrange-the-icons-manually-in-the-app-menu#comment47823_36607) or customize your stock app drawer (which comes originally with your phone.

[GO Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex), [AppDrawer (MIUI App Drawer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=JakedUp.AppDrawer&hl=en) and [Color App Drawer PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pro.smult.rainbowdrawer&hl=en) are good apps.

On the other hand you can find the sort icon in your app drawer (the green arrow) and select *Own order*. With that, you can arrange your app icons as you wish. You are allowed any number of drawer shelves (pages in the app drawer).

Comment: Are you sure that the "Own Order" is part of the stock android launcher, and not something that is added to your sony model?

Comment: @RyanConrad - Exactly. I could not find such options. :(

Comment: Well, you *have to* use apps as suggested then. :)

Comment: @Sid - Which version of Android is this? Is this built-in android launcher (com.android.launcher)

Comment: this is the stock app drawer on Xperia S running ICS. Cannot get to apps since I'm *not* rooted.

Comment: @Sid - please use [`@Reply`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/187824). So specific person can get notification about your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Using Android 4.1.x- 
Go to the all apps screen(not the home screen). 
Hit the menu button and choose "edit".
Press and hold the application icon you wish to relocate/edit/rearrange. 
Dragging the icon to the extreme right or left sides of the screen switch to the next/previous tiles.

Hope this helps :o)